# login in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I just installed wp lockdown plugin for wordpress so that user don't user sitename/wp-admin. It was a check mark that ask me if i want to hide wp-admin when not logged in so i checked that. Now i can't do anything.It will show this error when i wanna go to sitename/wp-admin :

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function theme_404_content() in F:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\mysite\404.php on line 25
```

Please help me so that i can fix this error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is explicit : you are using the function `theme_404_content` in the file `404.php` (line 25) of your theme, and this function does not exist.

Take a look at the file functions.php of your theme, the function `theme_404_content` should be defined here.

This error is in your theme and has nothing to do with wp lockdown.